# Does Python's jsonschema package allow for the use of numeric keys?

Tags: python, jsonschema

I'm ingesting a YAML file and validating it with a JSON schema. Some of the keys in the YAML are non-consecutive numbers, denoted in YAML as:

```
1:
    foo: bar
```

... Which in turn preserve their type when decoded into a Python `dict`.

I've tried validating this using the JSON schema `patternProperty` `^\\d+$`, but this fails because the regex is expecting a string, and doesn't perform type coercion.

Short of wrapping the keys in quotes in my source YAML file, is there an approach provided by the `jsonschema` package which lets me validate numeric keys?

Comment: keys in json are always strings! See here: https://json.org/

Comment: @Humbalan that's correct, but the same isn't true of Python's `dict`s. Any hashable value (which is _broadly_ anything except lists and dicts) can be a key, including numbers. Ditto for YAML.

Comment: It is not correct to compare a json structure with a dict in python. They seem equal. But one difference: json keys are strings. Look in the web page I mentioned above: A json objects starts with {, then there follows unconditionally a string.

Comment: @Humbalan I think you're missing the point of my question. A JSON schema is an (nominally) _arbitrary_ schema that's _described_ using JSON. It is often used to validate constraints not natively supported in JSON proper, and the JSON schema spec does include support for numeric key validation; I just haven't been able to find documentation about whether this is supported in the Python `jsonschema` package.

Comment: sorry, Jules, you are right. I din't read your question carefully.

Comment: @Jules You are mistaken. "JSON Schema is a vocabulary that allows you to annotate and validate JSON documents". Taken from http://json-schema.org/ It's the exact opposite of what you describe. It's a schema for validating JSON, that just happens to written in JSON.

Comment: @Dunes while that's nominally true, it does support features which aren't part of the JSON spec -- including these problematic numeric keys.

Comment: Don't know where you're getting your information from, but the latest draft of the [json-schema-validation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation/?include_text=1) document seems to make no allowances for objects having properties that are not strings. See sections 6.5.3 and 6.5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading your YAML in the wrong way.

There are multiple loaders and all but the BaseLoader actually try to
interpret non-quoted scalars by matching them with patterns. And that
is what gives you an integer for `1`, or a `datetime` for `2018-08-21 22:10:00`, or a boolean for `true`:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
1: 
   foo: bar
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(data)
```

gives:

```
{1: {'foo': 'bar'}}
```

but when changing `'safe'` to `'base'`:

```
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
```

you will get "string only" scalars:

```
{'1': {'foo': 'bar'}}
```

What would also work is the old syntax:

```
from ruamel import yaml

yaml.load(data, Loader=yaml.BaseLoader)
```

And that will also work with PyYAML (after adjusting the import)

Comment: This looks like it'll only work using the `ruamel` package; is there a way to get this functionality with the more popular `pyyaml` package?

Comment: Yes you can: do `import yaml; yaml.load(data, Loader=yaml.BaseLoader)` . (I am not sure if telling me that pyyaml is more popular was the best move to get me to answer that >:-) ).